# CSS: End a background linear-gradient after at a specified number of pixels before the end of the div

Tags: html, css

I have been experimenting with a top to bottom `linear-gradient` for a background of a page I am making.  The only problem is that there is a footer on the page and I would like to end the gradient before the end of the div.

Is this possible in CSS solely, or should the HTML be changed to create a div which ends before the footer begins?  Or should jQuery calculate the percentage at which the footer begins?

The pages are all different lengths, so ending by percentage would not work for all pages.  Can a linear gradient be ended, say 500px before the end of the div?

My code is here, the wrapper div extends for the full width of the page.

```
div#wrapper {
background: #ffdf96; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffdf96 0%, #a67f25 50%, #000 60%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffdf96), color-stop(50%,#a67f25), color-stop(60%,#000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffdf96 0%,#a67f25 50%,#000 60%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffdf96 0%,#a67f25 50%,#000 60%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffdf96 0%,#a67f25 50%,#000 60%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffdf96 0%,#a67f25 50%,#000 60%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffdf96', endColorstr='#a67f25',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

The page in context is here: http://bit.ly/1ar6KuR

Many thanks for any help that you can give :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not reverse the gradient color stops and reverse the direction from top --> bottom to bottom --> top and have the first color stop at the required pixel value.

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yHabt)

Or am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best way is to add `:before` pseudoclass and apply the gradient to that, like:

```css
#wrapper:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  content: "";
  ... and background here ...
}
```

or DIV inside #wrapper as the first child with the same CSS settings.

Comment: Thank you for this, this was a helpful idea.  In the end I added the gradient code to `.wrapper-holder`, and set the height of this box to be exactly above the footer on all pages using jQuery.